# textPath renders as skewed / path starting point and width aren't as assigned

Tags: html, css, svg

I've been trying to add textpath on my page, but it keeps showing up as slanted/skewed and I cannot figure out why.
I need the path to have dynamic width and fixed height. That seems to mess with the text, tho.

`preserveAspectRatio` makes the width and height of the path as desired, but the text gets skewed. Removing it keeps the text intact, but the path's dimensions then are `width: 376` and `height: 376`. It also then doesn't start at the assigned starting point (0,0).

Has anyone had this or something similar happen to them?

Here's my HTML:

```
<svg width="100%" height="376" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
   <path d="M0 0 L100 100" id="line-2"/>
   <text>
      <textPath xlink:href="#line-2" id="line-2-text" startOffset="60%">Hello</textPath>
   </text>
</svg>
```

And in SCSS I have:

```
svg {
    fill: $primary-color;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100vh;
    width: 100%;

    #line-2-text {
        fill: black;
        font: {
            family: $main-font;
            size: 12px;
            weight: bold;
        }
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a  preserveAspectRatio="none" on an svg that is not respecting the aspect ratio defined with the viewBox: <svg width="100%" height="376" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">

Comment: @enxanetane Yeah, that does preserve the text, but throws the dimension off. It makes the path's both `width` and `length="376"`, instead of 100% width and height "376"